# Could not reach Firestore (4.10.1) backend - using Android 8.1 (Oreo)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im having an issue in a a react app trying to use Firestore. When my app launches it immediately tries to load data from firestore. This worked fine when I was testing this on Android 7.1.1, however, on Android 8.1 I get the error: `Firestore(4.10.1): could not reach Firestore backend.` I'm pretty lost with this and have looked at other solutions but none have worked for me. Some people say they had this problem on 4.10.0 and that it was fixed in 4.10.1 but I'm still having a lot of trouble with this.

If any code would be useful for this please let me know - as far as I'm aware all the code for my app is working since it worked on Android 7.1.1

Thanks for any help :)

**SOLUTION**
Well this is awkward... The WiFi wasn't set up on the emulator for whatever reason since I just made it to test out the app on 8.1, everthing's working fine now!